# Lock Screen (Background) Notification - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal

I tested toast notification with the code below following [this](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/quickstart-sending-local-toast-win10/blob/master/BackgroundTaskComponent/ToastNotificationBackgroundTask.cs):

```cs
public static void ShowToastNotification(string message)
{
    ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
    {
        Visual = new ToastVisual()
        {
            BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
            {
                Children =
                {
                    new AdaptiveText()
                    {
                        Text = message
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(content.GetXml()));
}
```

And the Manifest looks like the following:

```xml
<VisualElements>
    ...
    <uap:LockScreen BadgeLogo="Assets\BadgeLogo.png" Notification="badgeAndTileText"/>
    ...
</VisualElements>
...
<BackgroundTasks>
    ...
    <Task Type="pushNotification"/>
    ...
</BackgroundTasks>
```

But it never pops up when screen is locked.

- I can see it when I unlock within few seconds.
- I cannot see the notification if I unlock like 15sec later or so cuz I set the duration to short.

> I checked the settings below:
>
> - I **enabled push notification** when I was declaring background task **in package manifest**,
> - I turned on **"Show notification on lock screen" in the windows settings**,
> - and I enabled my **app to run in background in the windows settings**.

**I can see it hits the background task (cuz other functions in the background work).**

What am I missing??

---

If there's a way to change the WELCOME MESSAGE instead, that would work for me too.

**I'm looking for a way to NOTIFY THE USER when error happens DURING LOG-IN.**

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: have you used `ToastNotifier ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code for UWP windows app and it works perfectly you just need to create a common function

```
using Windows.UI.Notifications;

public static void ShowToastNotification(string title, string stringContent)
{
    ToastNotifier ToastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();

    Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
    Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlNodeList toastNodeList = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");

    toastNodeList.Item(0).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(title));
    toastNodeList.Item(1).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(stringContent));

    Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
    Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
    audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-winsoundevent:Notification.SMS");
    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
    toast.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(4);
    ToastNotifier.Show(toast);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I already tried that too, but it had no difference; both codes work totally fine when screen is unlocked, but neither of them work when the screen is locked (log-in state)

Comment: ok then try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really sure where I can find the difference from my code above. Aren't they the same structure???

Comment: i think windows don't give permission if your windows is locked(loged in) even if you want to unlock it u need to enter the user name and password again.and then it will show you the notifications after logged in. every user has its own personal desktop application so operating system don't show you the notifications if your window is locked.

Comment: ohhh ok I see. So whether I change the whole settings like I've done above, it doesn't give me a 'true' permission to get notification when screen is locked, correct? That's sad :(  Thank you anyway for your help! :D

Comment: yup what ever settings you have done its saved for current logged user. even you can add any reminder in calendar it won't display notification if your system is locked. after logged in it shows the notification.  hope you understand then mark it as answer thank you :)